# Authoring HTML5 in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, html

What's the best solution for authoring HTML5 in Emacs? Is there a mode that will do conformance checking?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My best suggestion is to use [nxml-mode](http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode/) (available as packages in several linux distributions if you're on that platform) and load the html5 RelaxNG compact format specifications from [HTML5 specification page](http://syntax.whattf.org/relaxng/) (or any other source if you have one).

Nxml-mode validates xml files on the fly according to relaxNG specifications and give you nice customization features and handy functions for writing documents faster like inserting end-tags and such. Written by James Clark, so you know the author knows his XML.

If you load it like a system package you can probably just add it to your `auto-mode-alist` and be good to go. I have just set the following two variables for auto-completion and more docs is available at the first link.

```
(nxml-bind-meta-tab-to-complete-flag t)
(nxml-slash-auto-complete-flag t)
```

When it is loaded, just load the file you want and specify the location of the schema for html5,  save its location through the menu and you should be on your way. There are also more links to documentation on nxml-mode in the link I provided.

Comment: But HTML5 is not XML. You have two alternatives, use HTML5 with its proper syntax or using XML with the grammar of HTML5 (as XHTML). In the first solution the code `<input type=text name=foo required>` is correct, but the XML way is `<input type="text" name="foo" required="required" />`.

Comment: I find nxml-mode to be so excellent that I choose the HTML5 XML syntax *just* so I can edit and validate it with nxml-mode.

Comment: okay, HOW do I "load the html5 RelaxNG compact format specifications" ?

Comment: How do we run this mode? I am done including the file in my path and editing my .emacs file

Comment: You do not give any information on how to "load the html5 RelaxNG compact format specifications" in the context of Emacs. (the link is dead). The html5-schema package claims to "Add HTML5 schemas for use by nXML". The second line of a perfectly valid HTML 5 file, <html  lang="en"> is flagged as invalid. What am I missing?

Answer (score 20):

I've just seen this project, which apparently takes care of the necessary work to teach nxml-mode about HTML5:

http://github.com/hober/html5-el/tree/master

Comment: +1, that package made it exquisitely simple; just git clone, and add three statements to .emacs

Answer (score 7):

An easier to install solution may be web-mode. It definitely plays well with HTML5 and doesn't require you to jump through the XHTML hoops.

JavaScript and CSS blocks work as you would hope.

It also includes the ability to handle common templating languages like php, erb, handlebars, etc.

Check out http://web-mode.org for more details. It's available as a package, at least on MELPA.

Comment: I tried web mode and I was utterly disappointed. It doesn't even auto close tags and suggest offer easy attribute creation which even the basic HTML mode offers. The fact that I am a newbie to emacs may also have played a role though

Comment: web mode will auto close the correct tag for you if you type "</"

Answer (score 0):

I had nXML previously but found the schemas quite cumbersome to install, meaning I didn't get it to work with HTML5. I now use web-mode. Drawback is that there is no real-time validation. But that's cool as there are online-tools for that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend emmet mode. https://emmet.io/download/
This mode can be enabled in other editors rather than Emacs.