# Is there a pure HTML5 Emacs mode?

Tags: emacs, html

Question [Authoring HTML5 in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082474/authoring-html5-in-emacs) talks about nxml-mode but, from what I read, that can only be used for XHTML5, I want to use emacs with  HTML5 (no XML syntax). Is there any mode with auto-indentation, tag/attribute completion, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, the answer to that question is no at the moment. However HTML5 emerged relatively soon, so some Emacs support will certainly come up in the (not so)near future. XHTML 5 might seems to be a reasonable compromise at this point.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 can be written in either HTML or XHTML syntax (I know! Freaky!). So nxml-mode/nxhtml-mode work well if you prefer the latter style. I have not heard whether HTML or XHTML is considered "more correct" or a "better practice".

Comment: XHTML is more readily consumed by tools, so it's generally a better idea to work that way, and produce well-formed markup. (ie. It's easier to lint/validate etc.)