# Emacs, HTML5 not validating

Tags: jquery, html, schema, emacs23, nxhtml

I'm Writing a JQuery Mobile / PhoneGap app using Emacs 23.3. I'm using nXhtml, but for example, HTML5 data attributes are not validated. I'd like to use completion as well.

What's the recommended mode to use?

Does anyone actually use Emacs to edit HTML5, specifically JQuery Mobile pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authoring HTML5 in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082474/authoring-html5-in-emacs)

Comment: Thanks robert. That question is a few years old and I was hoping something new and better had come along.
I've since discovered a couple of issues with my config and managed to get it partially working. Emacs gives me joy when working with Erlang, but getting a good working html/javascript editing environment is taking days off my life!

Answer (score 1):

I use js3-mode, flymake-jshint, zencoding-mode, flymake-css, rainbow-mode in emacs for html5.